# Splitting an array of numbers into sorted groups

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I have an array with numbers whose absolute value is guaranteed to be less than 10.

What I'm doing now is sorting it in ascending order using `Array.prototype.sort()`:

```
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
})
```

But the task is to sort by groups without repeats, in other words having an array

`a = [1,2,2,3,1,4,4,2,9,8]`

I need to get the output

`b = [1,2,3,4,8,9,1,2,4]`

I had an idea to use `Array.prototype.push()` inside functional expression to add duplicate numbers to the end of the array. But for obvious reasons I can't do so because of the existence of a scope:

```
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    if(a === b){
        this.myArray.push(b);
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return a - b;
    }
})
```

Is it possible to implement my idea using `Array.prototype.sort()` or is it easier and more correct to write a separate function?

Comment: @MarkMeyer
Another example:
`a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]`
Desirable output:
`b = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: Sorry @Nikita — I misread the question and didn't see the example you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) by using a temporary object with a hashtable for the same group array. Take from it the length of the used array as group for sorting.

The sorting happens with group and value.

The result is mapped with index of the sorted temporary array.

```js
var array = [1,2,2,3,1,4,4,2,9,8],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = array
        .map((value, index) => ({ index, value, group: groups[value] = (groups[value] || 0 ) + 1 }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.group - b.group || a.value - b.value)
        .map(({ value }) => value);

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Why not `groups[value] = (groups[value] || 0) + 1` ? And why not `.map(({ value }) => value)` ?

Comment: Also `|| a.index - b.index` is superflouos (as long as no one is working with Number objects)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `group` object which creates each number as key and an array of the number as value. Then, loop through the object and add each number to output. Every time the array becomes empty, delete the key. Run this until the object has no keys left.

```js
const input = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 9, 8],
      group = {},
      output = [];

input.forEach(n => (group[n] = group[n] || []).push(n))

while (Object.keys(group).length > 0) {
  for (const key in group) {
    output.push(group[key].pop())

    if (group[key].length === 0)
      delete group[key];
  }
}

console.log(output)
```

(**Note**: For numerical keys, the keys of an object are traversed in the ascending order. So, this only works if there are natural numbers in the array)

Answer (score 1):

Below is on approach you can take - the comments have details of what each step is for:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 2, 9, 8];

//Create an occurrence map
const map = a.reduce((accum, i) => {
  if (accum[i]) {
    accum[i] += 1;
  } else {
    accum[i] = 1;
  }

  return accum;
}, {});

//We need to iterate the map as many times as the largest value
const iterations = Math.max(...Object.values(map));

const sorted = [];
for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i += 1) {
  Object.entries(map).forEach(entry => {
    const [val, count] = entry;
    if (count > 0) {
      sorted.push(parseInt(val)); //Add it to our sorted array
      map[val] -= 1; //Reduce the number of occurrences in the map for this key
    }
  });
}

console.log(sorted);
```